# Friction & Normal Reaction

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, friction, free-body-diagram

[image: Hibbler Chapter 8.1b][image: Hibbler Chapter 8.1d]P= Pulling

Any reference for the gradient of Normal Reaction.

Will *pushing* the weight lead to reversal of gradient?

Does this mean there is gradient of friction force (as it depends on normal reaction)?

While it seems that based on irregularities the reaction developed should be different at each point of contact between surfaces which would lead to different friction & *normal* force magnitudes at each point as illustrated in

[image: Hibbler Chapter 8.1c]

which supports intuition.

Comment: The resultant friction force is based on the resultant normal reaction as shown in the second diagram.

Answer (score 2):

You should realize that there is no complete microscopic understanding of friction. And I am inclined to think that there is no universal answer to your question that would hold in general.

This being said, it might be worth mentioning that since we are introduced to friction at an early stage in school, we get used to it and often don't realize how puzzling and counter-intuitive it actually is (at least I didn't). Think of the famous Amonton's law which states that total (dry) friction force $F_f$ is proportional to the $total$ reaction force $N$ as $F_f=\mu N$, where coefficient $\mu$ depends $only$ on the material of the contacting surfaces.

A moment of thought already reveals how counter-intuitive this is. Based on the cartoons like the bottom one in your question suggests the relation shouldn't be that simple. At least you might expect the friction to be proportional to the $pressure$ at the interface, but no, it is just the total reaction force and the coefficient of friction. How weird!

Comment: Great first two sentences! +1