# Normal Reaction Gradient (Redistribution of Normal Reaction)

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

In continuation of the previous Question - [Friction & Normal Reaction](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/781974/friction-normal-reaction/781996#781996)

[image][image]

Pardon me as I was not satisfied with answer in the above post. So re-asking in different form -

What leads to development of gradient of normal reaction in figure 2 when a pulling force P was applied compared with when no horizontal force is applied as in figure 1?

Comment: Rather than write a whole new question, you can edit the first. When you do that, the question goes to the top of the list of new/modified questions/answers (on the PSE homepage).

Answer (score 0):

Rotational stability.

Rather than doing an integration over all the $\Delta \bf N_{\rm n}$ I will use the resultant of all these normal forces.

Let the resultant of all $\Delta \bf N_{\rm n}$ be a force $\bf N$ pointing upwards and whose line of action is $x$ from the bottom right-hand corner, $A$.
$a$ is the distance of the lines of action of forces $\bf W$ and $\bf P$ from corner $A$.
The torque about corner $A$ must be zero otherwise there will be rotation anout corner $A$, thus $N\,x +P\,a - W\,a =0$.
Also $N-W=0$, thus $x = (1-\frac PW)a$.

When $P=0$ then $x=a$ as expected and when $P=W$ then $x=0$ and the object if on the point of tipping.

So that is where you gradient of $\Delta \bf N_{\rm n}$ comes from.